# comparing two fields in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

is their any query to pick certain date between two time stamps?The Problem is these two times stamps are set in two diffrent fields[image]

Comment: "to pick certain date"? - What does that mean?

Comment: I want to take **fs_id** between two dates, ie between fs_from and fs_two @Hanno Binder

Comment: So what is your 'input' value(s)/parameters? A single date value? - And you need to find the records which span across that single date?

Comment: What is the input date?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE fs_from > theDate AND fs_to < theDate;
```

I suggest to use prepared statements and insert a date object into the query.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `fs_from < theDate AND fs_to > theDate`?

Comment: Well no, it always confuses me, but I think it has to be `SELECT * FROM table WHERE fs_from < theDate AND fs_to < theDate;`

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion you can try in this way (If I really understood your question)

```
SELECT myFields FROM myTable 
     WHERE myCertainDate BETWEEN fs_from AND fs_to
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE fs_from > 'some date' 
AND   fs_to <  'some other date'
```

Comment: Wouldn't `fs_to` be greater than (or equal to) `fs_from` in any case?

Comment: So OP needs say records between two dates so say from 1-jan-2013 to 31-Dec-2013, so from should be greater than (and equal to) 1st jan 2013 and to date should be less than (and equal to) 31st Dec 2013. Hope helps?

Comment: Ok, I understand your interpretation. I'm still not sure what the OP really wants.

Answer (score 0):

Which date do you want?  You can choose a random date by doing:

```
select t.*,
       date_add(t.fs_from, interval cast(datediff(fs_to, fs_from) * rand() as int) day
               ) as ArbitraryDateBetweenTwoDates
from table t
```